# Delete a procedurally generated button

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line of code in a VBA project:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
```

Where it says "Button 1" I would like it to be linked to a variable of some sort.

The reason I ask is that I have a link on an "Index" worksheet that creates a new worksheet (a copy of a separate, template worksheet) using VBA and the newly created worksheet contains the above button. When I click that button on the new, copied worksheet, it should perform an action and then the button should be deleted.

The problem I'm facing is that the button name changes on each individual worksheet that is created.

In worksheet 5, it would be called "Button 5", in worksheet 6, it would be called "Button 6" etc. Due to this, the line of code above doesn't work as it's still referencing "Button 1".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to reference this correctly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will it be just 1 button?  What code creates the button?  Can it create the button with a name of Worksheet & "_BTN_FOR_UPDATE" for example, then it's easily found?

Comment: Get the Index of the sheet into a variable then change your line to the following: "ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button" & ShtIndex).Delete

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes it's only for one button on each worksheet. The button is on a template worksheet. When the template worksheet is copied, it also copies the button. If I'm thinking correctly no matter what the button is called on the template it

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Continued: will add 1 to whatever the button is called.

Comment: @Kathara I added SheetIndex = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index and 'ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button " & SheetIndex).Delete to the range however it didn't work as I also have the option to add/remove sheets. If I delete sheet 5 for example then whatever is on sheet 6 will be moved to Index number 5. So the button at that point will still be called Button 6 and the code will return Button 5. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: ok, well this wasn't considered. I believe you could search for the button (I don't know the code for that...) on each worksheet. I believe the answer down below might have a solution to your problem then :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting the button from code called by the button, it would be:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

After rereading your question more carefully I thought of this.
It catches all shapes on a sheet that start with "Button" regardless of the number.

```
Dim frmButton As Shape
For Each frmButton In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    If frmButton.Name Like "Button*" Then
        frmButton.Delete
    End If
Next
```

You could wrap the code above with the code below to go through multiple sheets.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.Name = "Sheet2" Then 'Exclude certain sheets "Sheet2" is excluded in this case.
        'Code
    End If
Next ws
```

## END OF EDIT

---

For an ActiveX control try:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEobjects("CommandButton1").Delete
```

Replace "Sheet1" and "CommandButton1" with the actual names as found in the properties, do not confuse this with the caption, especially for the button.

For a form control button try:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button 1").Delete
```

Replace the `ThisWorkbook` with `Workbooks("Book1")` if you are referring to a different workbook than the workbook the code resides in. Replace "Book1" with the actual name of the workbook.

Since the "Button 1" is a string, you can replace it with a variable containing a string, but beware you'll get an error if there is no shape with the name contained by the variable.